# How to use an OR condition with the Tendermint websocket /subscribe method?

Tags: tendermint, cosmos-sdk

What's the best way to implement an `OR` condition in the query of a Tendermint websocket `/subscribe` method?
https://docs.tendermint.com/master/rpc/#/Websocket/subscribe

Specifically I want to query `message.sender='${address}' OR transfer.recipient='${address}'`.
The solution I have right now is to do 2 `/subscribe` requests with the same jsonrpc id, but that's ugly, wasteful, and I have to filter out events that are triggered twice.

If I had `AND` and `NOT` then `a OR b = NOT((NOT a) AND (NOT b))`, but it doesn't seem like `NOT` is implemented: https://godoc.org/github.com/tendermint/tendermint/libs/pubsub/query#Operator

Thanks!

Comment: I'm told by the tm-core team that his seems like a feature that an outside contributor would be able to make relatively easy. They said it also seems like the type of issue that wouldn't need a lot of overhead reviewing the work (which means it could be merged quickly).

Would you mind making an issue on the [tm repo][1]? Maybe you could consider whether your team has the resources to implement it as outside contributors in order to see if happen quickly? Otherwise it could get triaged as a feature request in the Tendermint roadmap.


  [1]: https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint

Answer (score 3):

Last time I tried this on Tendermint 0.33,  Boolean conditions did not work in `/subscribe`

Answer (score 3):

Logical `OR` to join conditions isn't supported at present.

The query language is very simple right now. The only logical operator implemented to join separate conditions at present is `AND`, as per the [PEG](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/blob/98c595312af02037843b8fe74f0ee0625665448e/libs/pubsub/query/query.peg).

For example: `tm.event = 'Tx' AND tx.hash = 'XYZ' AND tx.height = 5`

Answer (score 3):

Bez from Tendermint Core has agreed to take this on! Here's [the issue](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/issues/5206) if you'd like to follow or contribute. He says he'll be able to focus on it after the p2p reactor refactor.